# Ubuntu detects two batteries when I only have one. How can I remove the other one?

Tags: battery

My laptop battery isn't detected by ubuntu, when I boot up my battery in the power indicator shows 100% charge no matter what. I can get it detected by applying a work around [found here](https://github.com/Icenowy/axpd/), but once I run this script I have two batteries detected, the one showing 100% and the actual battery.

Is there some way to remove the original "battery" which is detected?

Comment: Take a look under /proc/acpi/battery/ and see what's there. It may give you some clues as to what is going on.